# Unable to record using http recording controller with a proxy

Tags: jmeter, proxy

I have been trying to record my web application actions using the http recording controller in jmeter. I have added a recording controller, a test script recorder with proxy settings set. Certificate has been imported and installed. Also setup the proxy in the browser preferences for Chrome. But when I try to start and record the actions, none of them are being recorded in the recording controller. Am I missing something here?

Here are my settings:

```
Test Script Recorder - port 8989
OS Proxy settings - localhost, 8989
have installed the crt file generated on starting on Chrome under Trusted Root Certification Authorities
```

and the log generated when I started the recording:

```
2021-07-19 14:59:58,152 WARN o.a.j.p.h.p.ProxyControl: Could not open/read key store E:\Setup\apache-jmeter-5.4.1\bin\proxyserver.jks (The system cannot find the file specified), a new one will be created, ensure you install it in browser
java.io.FileNotFoundException: E:\Setup\apache-jmeter-5.4.1\bin\proxyserver.jks (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_271]
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_271]
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_271]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.ProxyControl.getKeyStore(ProxyControl.java:1651) ~[ApacheJMeter_http.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.ProxyControl.initDynamicKeyStore(ProxyControl.java:1529) [ApacheJMeter_http.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.ProxyControl.initKeyStore(ProxyControl.java:1480) [ApacheJMeter_http.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.ProxyControl.startProxy(ProxyControl.java:523) [ApacheJMeter_http.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.gui.ProxyControlGui.startProxy(ProxyControlGui.java:623) [ApacheJMeter_http.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.gui.ProxyControlGui.actionPerformed(ProxyControlGui.java:463) [ApacheJMeter_http.jar:5.4.1]
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_271]
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_271]
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_271]
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_271]
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_271]
    at com.github.weisj.darklaf.ui.button.DarkButtonListener.mouseReleased(DarkButtonListener.java:72) [darklaf-core-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_271]
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_271]
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_271]
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_271]
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_271]
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_271]
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_271]
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_271]
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_271]
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_271]
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_271]
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_271]
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_271]
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_271]
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_271]
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_271]
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_271]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_271]
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_271]
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_271]
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_271]
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_271]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_271]
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_271]
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_271]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_271]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_271]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_271]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_271]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_271]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_271]
2021-07-19 14:59:58,153 INFO o.a.j.p.h.p.ProxyControl: Creating HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder Root CA in E:\Setup\apache-jmeter-5.4.1\bin\proxyserver.jks, ensure you install certificate in your Browser for recording
2021-07-19 15:00:13,492 INFO o.a.j.p.h.p.ProxyControl: Created keystore in E:\Setup\apache-jmeter-5.4.1\bin\proxyserver.jks
2021-07-19 15:00:13,494 INFO o.a.j.p.h.p.Daemon: Creating Daemon Socket on port: 8989
2021-07-19 15:00:13,498 INFO o.a.j.p.h.p.Daemon: Test Script Recorder up and running!
2021-07-19 15:04:21,538 INFO o.a.j.p.h.p.Daemon: HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder stopped
```

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to say what's wrong without seeing:

1. Your [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html) configuration along with the screenshot of the test plan
2. Your operating system proxy configuration ([Chrome browser derives OS proxy setup](https://www.uniten.edu.my/media/1914/itms-configure-proxy-settings-chrome.pdf))
3. [JMeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging)

So the only piece of advice I can give you is to use [Recording Template feature](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#test_plan_building), it's available from `File -> Templates -> Recording` entry of JMeter's main menu, it should generate a good setup which saves captured HTTP requests under the [Recording Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Recording_Controller)

You might find [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-new-blazeMeter-chrome-extension-v4-easily-script-jmeter-and-selenium) easier to use, in this case you won't have to worry about proxies and certificates.

Comment: Right. Edited my question with details. Thanks.

Comment: I don't know what certificate you have "imported and installed", you log says that proxyserver.jks file is not there, the same applies to the certificates, you need to re-install the certificate after starting the proxy server. See [Recording HTTPS Traffic with JMeter's Proxy Server](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/recording-https-traffic-jmeters-proxy-server) article for more details if needed

Comment: There is a .crt file generated every time I start the recording. I import that from the Jmeter bin folder(after removing the traces from Chrome every time). I have re installed the certificate repeatedly but there is no change in the result. The same error log appears.

Comment: Do you have write access to `E:\Setup\apache-jmeter-5.4.1\bin\` folder? The certificate is valid for 7 days and it should be there for subsequent executions. If no `proxyserver.jks` is being generated - you won't be able to record secure traffic. Try [increasing JMeter logging verbosity for the proxy server](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging) by adding the next line to *log4j2.xml* file: `<Logger name="org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy" level="debug" />` and then look at [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging)

Answer (score 0):

If you use Firefox browser for your recording, you can get it working via an edit to `about:config` .
You can Google it, depending on the error you see.

It might be this one:

```
security.enterpise_roots.enabled = true
```

Or you could try:

Set `security.tls.version.fallback-limit` and `security.tls.version.max` to 3.

After that config change, your JMeter Recorder will probably work again.